# Windows backup gets partially successful due to regback files

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am trying to take a Windows back through Veritas Netbackup 8.0 of a Windows server 2012 R2. The backup is getting partially successful due to the following files which are inaccessible as they are being used by another user/process-

1. C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack
2. I had tried killing all the running process and server restart but still getting the same message.
3. Have checked with the vendor and they too confirmed that its an issue on OS level and requested to check the files if the files are corrupted.
4. Have took a local windows backup through windows server backup wizard and was successfully completed.

Are these files are required to be backedup? Can i add these files in the exclusion list? Let me know.

Comment: Shadow Volume Copy enabled on your backup job?

Comment: Hi, The VSS is enabled on my backup job.

Comment: These are the files which are skipped- C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\PeerDistRepub\PeerDistRepubStoreCatalog.pds
C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\DEFAULT
C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SAM
C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SECURITY
C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SOFTWARE
C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SYSTEM (WI